Clerk expo redirecting me to browser, instead of showing me list of google accounts in a popup
When it comes to authentication in react native, there's no better way than using clerk in expo, as always, its my favorite. but coming to social login with google, in clerk in expo, it was redirecting me to mobile browser, instead of showing me a popup containing all of my google accounts. as you know all of you, this should be not like that, many mobile apps are using this popup method showing all google accounts for user compatibility. and for user's easiness. please give me code how can I do that in my react native expo app.
My login/signup expo screen for authentication, I've followed one YouTube channel (Simon grimm) for this code:

import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { KeyboardAvoidingView } from "react-native";
import Loading from "../../components/shared/loading";
import { images } from "../../constants";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import CustomButton from "../../components/CustomButton";
import { Link, router, useLocalSearchParams } from "expo-router";
import {
  useSignIn,
  useSignUp,
  useAuth,
  useOAuth,
  useClerk,
} from "@clerk/clerk-expo";
import { Alert } from "react-native";
import { useWarmUpBrowser } from "../../hooks/useWarmUpBowser";
import axios from "axios";
import { sensitiveConstants } from "../../constants/sensitiveConstants";
const Google = "oauth_google";
const LinkedIn = "oauth_linkedIn";
const Facebook = "oauth_facebook";
const Login = () => {
  const { user } = useClerk();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useWarmUpBrowser();
  // FIXME: FROM NOW, SOCIAL AUTH WILL START

  const { startOAuthFlow: facebookAuth } = useOAuth({
    strategy: "oauth_facebook",
  });
  const { startOAuthFlow: googleAuth } = useOAuth({ strategy: "oauth_google" });
  const { startOAuthFlow: linkedInAuth } = useOAuth({
    strategy: "oauth_linkedin",
  });
  const onSelectAuth = async (strategy) => {
    const selectedAuth = {
      [Google]: googleAuth,
      [LinkedIn]: linkedInAuth,
      [Facebook]: facebookAuth,
    }[strategy];
    try {
      const { createdSessionId, setActive } = await selectedAuth();

      try {
        if (createdSessionId) {
          setActive({ session: createdSessionId });
          //FIXME: SAVE IN DATABASE
          axios
            .post(`URL_ENDPOINT_FOR_MY_WEBSITE`, {
              clerkId: user?.id,
              email: user?.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress,
              image: user?.imageUrl,
            })
            .then(() => console.log("Created user inmongodb"))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
          router.replace("/home");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("OAuth error: ", error);
    }
  };

  // FIXME: FROM NOW, EMAIL AUTH WILL START

  const { type } = useLocalSearchParams();
  const { signIn, setActive, isLoaded } = useSignIn();
  const {
    signUp,
    isLoaded: signUpLoaded,
    setActive: signUpSetActive,
  } = useSignUp();

  const [emailAddress, setEmailAddress] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Component mounted or updated.");
  }, []);
  const onSignUpPress = async () => {
    if (!signUpLoaded) return;
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const result = await signUp.create({ emailAddress, password });

      if (result.createdSessionId) {
        signUpSetActive({ session: result.createdSessionId });
        //FIXME: SAVE IN DATABASE
        axios
          .post(`URL_ENDPOINT_FOR_MY_WEBSITE`, {
            clerkId: result.createdUserId,
            email: result.emailAddress,
            image: user?.imageUrl,
          })
          .then(() => console.log("Created user inmongodb"))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      } else {
        console.log("No session created", result);
        Alert.alert("Sign-up was unsuccessful. Please try again.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("SignUp error:", error);
      Alert.alert(
        error.errors ? error.errors[0].message : "An unknown error occurred."
      );
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const onSignInPress = async () => {
    if (!isLoaded) return;
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const result = await signIn.create({
        identifier: emailAddress,
        password,
      });
      console.log("result", result);
      if (result.createdSessionId) {
        setActive({ session: result.createdSessionId });
      } else {
        console.log("No session created", result);
        Alert.alert("Sign-in was unsuccessful. Please try again.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("SignIn error:", error);
      Alert.alert(
        error.errors ? error.errors[0].message : "An unknown error occurred."
      );
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return loading ? (
    <Loading />
  ) : (
    <SafeAreaView className="h-full bg-white">
      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
          <Image
            source={images.logo}
            style={{
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              alignSelf: "center",
              marginVertical: 10,
            }}
          />
          <View className="mb-[20px]">
            <Text className="text-[30px] font-lbold ">
              {type === "login" ? "Welcome!" : "Sign Up"}
            </Text>
            <Text className="text-gray font-lblack text-[15px]">
              {type === "login"
                ? "Please login to continue our app"
                : "Create a new account"}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View className="mb-[30px]">
            <Text className="font-lbold text-[25px] ml-[5px]">Email</Text>
            <TextInput
              className="mx-[4px] mb-[10px] rounded-[12px] h-[50px] border-[2px] border-theme p-[10px] bg-[#fff]"
              autoCapitalize="none"
              placeholder="Email"
              value={emailAddress}
              onChangeText={setEmailAddress}
            />
            <Text className="font-lbold text-[25px] ml-[5px]">Password</Text>
            <TextInput
              className="mx-[4px] rounded-[12px] h-[50px] border-[2px] border-theme p-[10px] bg-[#fff]"
              autoCapitalize="none"
              placeholder="Password"
              value={password}
              secureTextEntry
              onChangeText={setPassword}
            />
            <Link href={"/reset"} asChild>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text className="text-gray font-lblack text-[15px] text-end self-end">
                  {type === "login" && "Forgot Password?"}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Link>
          </View>
          {type === "login" ? (
            <CustomButton
              handlePress={onSignInPress}
              title={"Login"}
              textStyles={"text-white text-[23px]"}
              containerStyles={"rounded-full w-full py-[10px]"}
            />
          ) : (
            <CustomButton
              handlePress={onSignUpPress}
              title={"Create account"}
              textStyles={"text-white"}
              containerStyles={"rounded-full w-full py-[10px]"}
            />
          )}
          <View className="mt-[10px] flex-row justify-center">
            <Text className="text-[23px]">or</Text>
          </View>
          <View>
            <CustomButton
              title={"Continue with Facebook"}
              containerStyles={
                "mt-7 w-full bg-[#486CB4] rounded-full py-[20px]"
              }
              handlePress={() => onSelectAuth(Facebook)}
              iconLeft={true}
              iconName={"logo-facebook"}
              textStyles={"text-white font-lbold"}
              iconColor={"#fff"}
            />
            <CustomButton
              title={"Continue with Google"}
              textStyles={"text-gray-500 text-[20px] font-lbold"}
              iconColor={"#000"}
              handlePress={() => onSelectAuth(Google)}
              containerStyles={"mt-7 w-full rounded-full py-[20px]"}
              iconLeft={true}
              outline={true}
              outlineColor={"#ccc"}
              iconName={"logo-google"}
            />
            <CustomButton
              title={"Continue with LinkedIn"}
              textStyles={"text-gray-500 text-[20px] font-lbold"}
              iconColor={"#000"}
              handlePress={() => onSelectAuth(LinkedIn)}
              containerStyles={"mt-7 w-full rounded-full py-[20px]"}
              iconLeft={true}
              outline={true}
              outlineColor={"#ccc"}
              iconName={"logo-linkedin"}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Login;

